# Subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql when using select

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, user and topic.

table user

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usertype` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `useraccesskey` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userphone` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userpassword` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usernickname` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userphoto` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

table topic

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
 `topicid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `btid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topictitle` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `topiccontent` text NOT NULL,
 `topicisdel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topicdate` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `authorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `useraccesskey` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `topicistop` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `topicishot` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`topicid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1605 ;
```

I use this sql query to list all infos

```
select b.*, (select userphoto from user u where u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey) as headpic, (select usernickname from user u where u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey) as nickname from topic b where b.topicisdel = 0 and b.btid = 3 order by b.topicistop desc, b.topicishot desc, b.topicid desc"
```

but the result tells me `Subquery returns more than 1 row`, but i checked all infos, there's no, I don't know why, please help me, thanks.

Comment: you mean to say there is no record but it says more that one record is there?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh sorry, I mean there are some records, but no the same, I don't know why, thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and what are you getting in result, it is not clear.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a subquery at all :-$

Comment: @Strawberry I'm newer to study coding, can you tell me the right query to do this? thank you

Comment: If I knew what you (thought you) were doing, I might be able to

Comment: @Strawberry I want to get each topic and the user's infos who created this topic.

Comment: @Strawberry each info should like this  ` topicid topictitle userphone usernickname, userphoto `, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you're after something more like this - although without a data set and a result set, it's always stupidly hard to be sure...

```
select b.*
     , u.userphoto headpic
     , u.usernickname nickname
  from topic b
  join user u
    on u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey 
 where b.topicisdel = 0 
   and b.btid = 3 
 order 
    by b.topicistop desc
     , b.topicishot desc
     , b.topicid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one row being returned by the subquery in the `SELECT` list. MySQL can only deal with one scalar value in that context, so we have to guarantee that the subquery doesn't return two or more rows.

The "quick fix" to avoid the error is to add a LIMIT 1 on each of the subqueries, so that it returns *at most* one row.

I'd also recommend an `ORDER BY` to make the result more deterministic. We don't see what other columns are contained in `user` table, so I just referenced the column being returned by the `SELECT`.

For example:

```
SELECT b.*
     , ( SELECT u.userphoto 
           FROM user u
          WHERE u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey
          ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1                -- return at most one row
       ) AS headpic
     , ( SELECT u.usernickname 
           FROM user u 
          WHERE u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey
          ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1                -- return at most one row
       ) AS nickname
  FROM topic b 
 WHERE b.topicisdel = 0 
   AND b.btid = 3
 ORDER
    BY b.topicistop DESC
     , b.topicishot DESC
     , b.topicid DESC
```

I don't think that's the "best" solution to the problem. I've attempted to explain what is causing the issue, and one possible way to workaround it.

To see where there's more than one row being returned, we can add another subquery to the SELECT list...

```
     , ( SELECT u.userphoto 
           FROM user u
          WHERE u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey
          ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1,1              -- return value from 2nd row if it exists
       ) AS headpic_2
```

If `userphoto` can be NULL, that may not give us much of an indication, because we won't be able to distinguish between a NULL return from a row, or a NULL returned because a row doesn't exist.

We can get a count of matching rows from user with another subquery in the SELECT list:

```
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM user u
          WHERE u.useraccesskey = b.useraccesskey
       ) AS count_matching_rows_in_user
```

Note that `useraccesskey` column is not guaranteed to be unique in `user`. Absent that guarantee, we have to expect that there may be duplicate values, that is, more than one row in `user` that has the same value for `useraccesskey`.